# Firebase iOS push notification receiving but sometimes not?

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented push notification in my iOS App using `Firebase SDK` and I am successfully getting push notifications from `Firebase console` as well as from server.

But on many occasions, I wait and wait, and even send 5-6 notifications from Firebase console but not received on App. I tried to change network (both Mobile data & WiFi) but still not receiving. After waiting for an hour and more, suddenly it starts working (I am not re-installing App).

What may be the reason? If network is an issue, then why is it not woking though I change my network to WiFi having good bandwidth?

Comment: I have EXACTLY this issue. Did you get anywhere with it?

Comment: Be sure sequence of code is proper.. for example, first you need to set delegate for push notification, then configure Firebase. I will send you soon

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. I will really appreciate this help.

Comment: I will add code snippet as an answer which may help you..

Comment: Can you tell me your exact issue? Are you not getting push notification sometimes? Or never getting?

Comment: Sometimes. I'll try everything, and they don't come. I try in a few hours, and everything works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216585/discussion-between-nspratik-and-rjb).

Comment: Do you have any code to help me?